# Given a vector of any type, how can I get an NA value of the same class?

Tags: r, class, types, na

Suppose I want to do something like:

```
mask_values <- function(x, mask) ifelse(mask, x, NA)
```

The purpose of this function is to take a vector and replace some of its values with NA based on the value of `mask`. However, this function doesn't guarantee that the return type is always the same as the input `x`. For example:

```
date_vec <- rep(lubridate::today(), 10)
my_mask <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), length.out = 10)
class(mask_values(date_vec, my_mask))
```

which yields `"numeric"` rather than the desired `"Date"`. So I try switching to `dplyr::if_else`, which is supposed to preserve types:

```
mask_values <- function(x, mask) dplyr::if_else(mask, x, NA)
class(mask_values(date_vec, my_mask))
```

However, `if_else` also requires the *input* types to be the same as each other, and `NA` has type "logical", which means I get this error:

```
Error: `false` must be a `Date` object, not a logical vector.
```

So it seems that if I want to use `if_else` in order to preserve the input type, I need to be able to obtain an NA value with the same class as the input. Is there a reliable way to do this for any class? One possibility seems to be `x[NA]`, but I'm not sure if that is a universal solution or if it just happens to work with the examples that I've tested. You can assume that the only classes that matter are "vector-like" classes for which NA values exist, such as Date and POSIXct, as well as all the basic R data types (logical, character, numeric, etc.).

Alternatively, is there another way to implement my `mask_values` function such that the return value always has the same type as `x`?

Comment: x[mask] <- NA will preserve type and class of x (because NA is of type logical and thus won't ever be of higher type than x).

Comment: Or even better, use is.na(x) <- mask.

Comment: If you want to post any or all of these as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding `ifelse` whenever possible. It is quite inefficient and as you have seen also quirky regarding what it returns (although that is well documented). I rarely use it and, if I do use it, only for interactive use and not programmatically.

The canonical and safe way of setting values to `NA` in base R is `is.na<-`. (Note that it supports logical and positional indexing. `mask` could also be a numeric vector.)

```
mask_values <- function(x, mask) {
  is.na(x) <- mask
  x
}

#or simply this:
#mask_values <- `is.na<-` 
#i.e., `is.na<-` is already what you want.

class(mask_values(date_vec, my_mask))
#[1] "Date"
```

Alternatively, you can also use simple subset-assignment. `NA` is a logical value. (If you create it like this. It can be coerced to other types and of course you can specify it as other types with `NA_real_` etc.) If you assign a logical vector into any other vector, it will be coerced to that other vector's type (because "logical" is the most primitive type).

```
mask_values <- function(x, mask) {
  x[mask] <- NA
  x
}

class(mask_values(date_vec, my_mask))
#[1] "Date"
```

Btw., this subset-assignment is how the `is.na<-.default` method is defined.

I prefer doing subset-assignment explicitly in my code but occasionally the convenience function `replace` can be useful.